# How can I check glsl code in command line?

Tags: opengl, vim, glsl, minecraft, micro-editor

I'm editing shaders for Minecraft pe on my phone via ssh using a KDE terminal on my computer.
Syntax highlighting works good, but it does not show even simplest errors.
For example in this code below I have at list two errors, mostly lexical

```
vec4 no`rm`alColor;

void main(){
    nomralColor = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);//vec3 != vec4
    gl_FragColor = nomralColor;//normalColorl != nomralColor
}
```

Is there any possible way to check glsl code for simplest (at list lexical) errors using one of available command line code editors (nano/vim/micro)?

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/Reference-Compiler

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making a little tool you can use to check. The following code just prints out the error in the console window. You could be coding in C++ or Java for Android, I'll give you my C++ example because all the OpenGL calls are the same in Java too.

It's pretty short really, you just use `glCreateShader()` and `glCompileShader()` to try to compile it, followed by `glGetShaderInfoLog()` to give you the error message(s).

```
//tell openGL to do all the work for us
bool compileShader(GLuint shaderID, std::string shaderCode) {
    // Compile Shader
    glShaderSource(shaderID, 1, (const char* const*)shaderCode.c_str(), NULL);
    glCompileShader(shaderID);

    // Check Shader
    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    // Do we have an error message?
    if (InfoLogLength > 0){
        std::vector<char> shaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength + 1);
        // Get the message text
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &shaderErrorMessage[0]);

#ifdef DBG_SHADER
        printf("Compilation error:\n%s", &shaderErrorMessage[0]);
#endif

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and the usage of that function is, given a string of code called `FragmentShaderCode`

```
GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
bool succeeded = compileShader(FragmentShaderID, FragmentShaderCode);
```

Comment: Is it able to handle "includes" too?